# Changing WPF Decorator Child Base on a Property Value

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF control whose content completely depends on a property of its data context.  For the sake of this, let's just say the control's DataContext is of type Product, which has a Status property of InStock, OutOfStock, or Discontinued.

I have individual user controls for each of those status types.  I could, and have, created some kind of panel that binds the visiblity of each to Product.Status.  But that created problems, since some of the user controls ended up with funky stuff because some depend on various properties being set.  And in my actual application, there are many statuses, so the visualtree gets too big for my taste.

I solved the problem by creating  and in my code, I check for a status change on the DataContext and set the appropriate child in a big switch statement.  I would like to do this in XAML if possible.  I want the child to be set on demand, so I assume I'll need to use templates.  Something like this:
SwitchControl would derive from Decorator or Border, whatever.

```
<SwitchControl Property="Status">
  <SwitchControl.Possibilities>
    <Possibility Value="Discontinued">
       <Possibility.Template>
            <DiscontinuedView />
       </Possibility.Template>
    </Possibility>
    <Possibility Value="InStock">
       <Possibility.Template>
            <InStockView />
       </Possibility.Template>
    </Possibility>
  <SwitchControl.Possibilities />
</SwitchControl>
```

It would be even better if I could shorten the whole thing to:

```
<SwitchControl>
    <Possibility Value="Discontinued">
      <DiscontinuedView />
    </Possibility>
    <Possibility Value="InStock">
      <InStockView />
    </Possibility>
</SwitchControl>
```

Point being, only one child would exist at any given time.  Anyone know of a way to get this done?  I looked around in MVVM frameworks and couldn't find anything.  Otherwise I'll experiment with creating a custom control myself.

Comment: one possible way is to create Triggers for your property and change control Template in a trigger setter. different templates can be defined separately and stored in Resources

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [DataTemplateSelector class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This allows you to define templates based on different criteria, e.g. the type of the current `DataContext`. An example could look somewhat like the following:

```
public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
            public DataTemplate DiscontinuedDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate InStockDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate OutOfStockDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var product = item as Product;
        switch (product.Status)
        {
            case Status.InStock:
                return InStockDataTemplate;
            case Status.Discontinued:
                return DiscontinuedDataTemplate;
            case Status.OutOfStock:
                return OutOfStockDataTemplate;
        }
        // Fallback
        return DiscontinuedDataTemplate;
    }
}
```

...and use it in the following way:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DiscontinuedDataTemplate">
       <DiscontinuedView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="InStockDataTemplate">
       <InStockView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="OutOfStockDataTemplate">
        <OutOfStockView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- DataTemplate Selector -->
    <local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTemplateSelector"
          DiscontinuedDataTemplate="{StaticResource DiscontinuedDataTemplate}" 
          InStockDataTemplate="{StaticResource InStockDataTemplate}"
          OutOfStockDataTemplate="{StaticResource OutOfStockDataTemplate}"/>
</Window.Resources>

<ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}" Content="{Binding Product}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion andreask.  I ended up creating a control that I think solves the problem more directly.  I've been working on a WPF helper library that I'll post to nuget in the future, but if you want to use it now, it's at:

https://gist.github.com/StevePotter/b17f8d4b2657a2d2610390a11fb57e03

Example XAML is included.  I hope this is useful for someone!